# How to save ALAsset song/Audio file to User's Directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
 MPMediaQuery * query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];<br> //if you need to enumerate songs
 for(MPMediaItem * item in query.items){ .... }
```

I have checked everywhere, but couldn't find anything helpful. Your suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: Please visit this link for more detail, i think this may help you. [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077725/application-crashed-while-importing-songs-from-ipod-library-in-iphone-for-ios-5)