# How can i record a song play from iPod library using MPMediaPickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am making an App in which i have to play music from iPod Music Library using MPMediaPickerController.After playing a song i want to record the song with some external Voice(For example:- User's Voice).I m trying to do the same but getting a problem i.e.when App launches firstly,i choose a song from iPod Music library after that i click on start Recording Button.when i click on Start Recording button my song which i played before stops but the recording is working properly.Recording of User's Voice is working fine but song is not getting recorded as i told that song stops when "Start Recording" button clicked.I am using AVAudioRecorder for Recording.This is my code which i m using.

```
-(Void)ViewDidLoad
{
self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
}
- (void)playOrPauseMusic:(id)sender {
MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = self.musicPlayer.playbackState;
if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped || playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused) {
    [self.musicPlayer play];
} else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
    [self.musicPlayer pause];
}
}

- (void)openMediaPicker:(id)sender {
MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO; // this is the default   
[mediaPicker shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
}

- (void) startRecording
{   
[self.musicPlayer play];
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
err = nil;
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// We can use kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 (4:1 compression) or kAudioFormatLinearPCM for nocompression
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

// We can use 44100, 32000, 24000, 16000 or 12000 depending on sound quality
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];

// We can use 2(if using additional h/w) or 1 (iPhone only has one microphone)
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

[recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
[recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] ;

NSLog(@"recorderFilePath: %@",recorderFilePath);

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];

err = nil;

NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&err];
if(audioData)
{
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fm removeItemAtPath:[url path] error:&err];
}

err = nil;
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
if(!recorder){
    NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: [err localizedDescription]
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    return;
}

//prepare to record
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
if (! audioHWAvailable) {
    UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [cantRecordAlert show];

    return;
}

// start recording
[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 2];

lblStatusMsg.text = @"Recording...";
selector:@selector(handleTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

This is my Code of MPMusicPlayer and AVAudioRecorder.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't record Songs imported from iPod library, you can only record mp3 file, for that you need to convert Mediaitem into mp3 format.

you can get referance for that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077725/application-crashed-while-importing-songs-from-ipod-library-in-iphone-for-ios-5), i hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into playing two tracks simultaneously. You could record a separate voice over track and trigger this and your mp3 to start playing at the same time. Obviously this would only work inside your app.