# Accessing media library in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to access songs from media library and then want to cut a part of that song.
I have written function to cut a song from bundle and it is working fine.
Now I want to allow user to select song from library, how can I do that?

Comment: Just read out [this post][1] i think this may help you for what you want.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077725/application-crashed-while-importing-songs-from-ipod-library-in-iphone-for-ios-5

Answer (score 1):

Just like how you access all other media in ios- using AssetsLibrary, more about this here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html

Be aware that all the media is read only and you can manipulate only a copy of the songs and not the original.

Comment: So is there a way to write to the media library?