# get all the songs from music library ios swift 3 xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift3

i wanna get all the songs from music library and show in my table view and then select multiple songs in table view and play in AVAudioPlayer. but i am unable to get songs from music library and show in my table view.i visit many links but did not work for me, please help me. here is my code

```
@IBAction func selectMusicFromGallery(_ sender: Any) 
{
    mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    mediaPicker.delegate = self
   // mediaPicker.prompt = "Select Songs"
    self.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) 
{
    let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songs().items
    let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mediaItems!)
    let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
    player.setQueue(with: mediaCollection)
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: This will not work in simulator. Did you try in a device ?

Comment: Refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077725/application-crashed-while-importing-songs-from-ipod-library-in-iphone-for-ios-5]

Comment: look this [http://iphoneghostrider.blogspot.in/2014/05/import-music-and-save-it-to-document.html]

Comment: Yes i try in device but did not work. it just go to the ITunes library but did not grab songs from library to my tableView

Comment: @IrfanSaeed please check my code. it may be help this code

Comment: Thanks @YogendraGirase. it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks to @Sneha  for your moral Support.

Comment: Thanks to @Jack for you support Dude. (y)

Answer (score 14):

You can use this SongQuery.swift class

//
    //  SongQuery.swift
    //

```
import Foundation
import MediaPlayer

struct SongInfo {

    var albumTitle: String
    var artistName: String
    var songTitle:  String

    var songId   :  NSNumber
}

struct AlbumInfo {

    var albumTitle: String
    var songs: [SongInfo]
}

class SongQuery {

    func get(songCategory: String) -> [AlbumInfo] {

        var albums: [AlbumInfo] = []
         let albumsQuery: MPMediaQuery
        if songCategory == "Artist" {
            albumsQuery = MPMediaQuery.artists()

        } else if songCategory == "Album" {
            albumsQuery = MPMediaQuery.albums()

        } else {
            albumsQuery = MPMediaQuery.albums()
        }


       // let albumsQuery: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.albums()
        let albumItems: [MPMediaItemCollection] = albumsQuery.collections! as [MPMediaItemCollection]
      //  var album: MPMediaItemCollection

        for album in albumItems {

            let albumItems: [MPMediaItem] = album.items as [MPMediaItem]
           // var song: MPMediaItem

            var songs: [SongInfo] = []

            var albumTitle: String = ""

            for song in albumItems {
                if songCategory == "Artist" {
                    albumTitle = song.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist ) as! String

                } else if songCategory == "Album" {
                    albumTitle = song.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle ) as! String


                } else {
                    albumTitle = song.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle ) as! String
                }

                let songInfo: SongInfo = SongInfo(
                    albumTitle: song.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle ) as! String,
                    artistName: song.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist ) as! String,
                    songTitle:  song.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle ) as! String,
                    songId:     song.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID ) as! NSNumber
                )
                songs.append( songInfo )
            }

            let albumInfo: AlbumInfo = AlbumInfo(

                albumTitle: albumTitle,
                songs: songs
            )

            albums.append( albumInfo )
        }

        return albums

    }

    func getItem( songId: NSNumber ) -> MPMediaItem {

        let property: MPMediaPropertyPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate( value: songId, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID )

        let query: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery()
        query.addFilterPredicate( property )

        var items: [MPMediaItem] = query.items! as [MPMediaItem]

        return items[items.count - 1]

    }

}
```

**And For your View Controller Code Show songs in table view controller**

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView?
    let myTableView: UITableView = UITableView( frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped )

    var albums: [AlbumInfo] = []
    var songQuery: SongQuery = SongQuery()
    var audio: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Songs"
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            if status == .authorized {
                self.albums = self.songQuery.get(songCategory: "")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
                    self.tableView?.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0;
                    self.tableView?.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                self.displayMediaLibraryError()
            }
        }

    }

    func displayMediaLibraryError() {

        var error: String
        switch MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus() {
        case .restricted:
            error = "Media library access restricted by corporate or parental settings"
        case .denied:
            error = "Media library access denied by user"
        default:
            error = "Unknown error"
        }

        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error, preferredStyle: .alert)
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }))
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return albums.count
    }

    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int ) -> Int  {

        return albums[section].songs.count
    }

    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "MusicPlayerCell",
            for: indexPath) as! MusicPlayerCell
        cell.labelMusicTitle?.text = albums[indexPath.section].songs[indexPath.row].songTitle
        cell.labelMusicDescription?.text = albums[indexPath.section].songs[indexPath.row].artistName
        let songId: NSNumber = albums[indexPath.section].songs[indexPath.row].songId
        let item: MPMediaItem = songQuery.getItem( songId: songId )

        if  let imageSound: MPMediaItemArtwork = item.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork ) as? MPMediaItemArtwork {
            cell.imageMusic?.image = imageSound.image(at: CGSize(width: cell.imageMusic.frame.size.width, height: cell.imageMusic.frame.size.height))
        }
        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return albums[section].albumTitle
    }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let songId: NSNumber = albums[indexPath.section].songs[indexPath.row].songId
    let item: MPMediaItem = songQuery.getItem( songId: songId )
    let url: NSURL = item.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL ) as! NSURL
    do {
        audio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
        guard let player = audio else { return }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    self.title = albums[indexPath.section].songs[indexPath.row].songTitle
  }
}
```

**

> Don't Forgot add frameworks MediaPlayer.framework,
>   MediaToolbox.framework, AudioToolbox.framework

**

Comment: I am looking for something like this and found your code, but when I try to run, it returns an error that says that the MusicPlayerCell type is not declarated. I'm new to swift and to building iOS apps, so I'm not very sure what happen... Is there any problem between version types, or updated types between classes?

Comment: @DavidGonzálezBlazman you need to create a custom table view cell

Comment: And here is the plist permision:             <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>Play using while you are hiking</string>

Comment: how to play a selected local media song?

Comment: @Fido I have Updated code Selected play local media song.

Comment: @YogendraGirase Thanks great help